# İnstagram OAuthAccessTokenException Error

Tags: php, api, instagram

```
        stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object (
     [code] => 400 [error_type] => OAuthAccessTokenException
 [error_message] => The access_token provided is invalid. ) )
```

This is my error. It says Token is invalid but i check the token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/
and in there it says token is valid. I didnt get any "Permissions and Features" the program still in developent status so do i need to get the Permissions to do anything after getting Token ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your apicall to last mode on developer.facebook